C++ Builder Error. Vcl.Buttons.hpp(44): candidate found by name lookup is 'Vcl'
When I create simple project in C++ Builder and add component on a From from my Package - EhLib I get next compilation error.
[bcc32c Error] Vcl.Buttons.hpp(66): reference to 'Vcl' is ambiguous
  Vcl.Buttons.hpp(44): candidate found by name lookup is 'Vcl'
  EhLib.VCL.hpp(48): candidate found by name lookup is 'Ehlib::Vcl'

I can't figure out the reason for the error.
When creating a similar project in Delphi, no errors occur.
I use Embarcadero® RAD Studio 12 Version 29.0.53982.0329
I can't make a minimal project to reproduce the error yet because the EhLib package contains quite a lot of files and code.
I found the following using namespace statement in the EhLib.VCL.Hpp file, But I can't delete it because this file is automatically generated by the system based on the pas file.
File EhLib.VCL.hpp
...
    extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::Types::TPoint __fastcall SafeGetMouseCursorPos(void);
    extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetEhLibGUISysInfoAsString(void);
    extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetEhLibFullSysInfoAsString(void);
    }   /* namespace Vcl */
    }   /* namespace Ehlib */
    #if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB_VCL)
    using namespace Ehlib::Vcl;
    #endif
    #if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB)
    using namespace Ehlib;
    #endif
    #pragma pack(pop)
    #pragma option pop
    
    #pragma delphiheader end.

I don't use using namespace in my code at all. All using namespace statements are in the automatically generated hpp files, which are not recommended to be changed.
I can't add the whole source file because stackoverflow limits text to 30,000 characters, so I'm only adding the parts that look important.
File Unit1.cpp. The file that I can edit.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "MemTableDataEh"
#pragma link "MemTableEh"
#pragma link "DBAxisGridsEh"
#pragma link "DBGridEh"
#pragma link "DBGridEhGrouping"
#pragma link "DBGridEhToolCtrls"
#pragma link "DynVarsEh"
#pragma link "EhLib.VCL"
#pragma link "GridsEh"
#pragma link "ToolCtrlsEh"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
//
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

File Vcl.Buttons.hpp. I can't edit this file. It is part of the base VCL library.
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2024 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'Vcl.Buttons.pas' rev: 36.00 (Windows)

#ifndef Vcl_ButtonsHPP
#define Vcl_ButtonsHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
#endif
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>
#include <SysInit.hpp>
#include <Winapi.Windows.hpp>
#include <Winapi.Messages.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Graphics.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Winapi.CommCtrl.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ImgList.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Themes.hpp>
#include <System.UITypes.hpp>
#include <System.Generics.Collections.hpp>
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Generics.Defaults.hpp>
#include <System.Types.hpp>
#include <System.Actions.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Menus.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ActnList.hpp>

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _WIN64
#pragma link "dwmapi.lib"
#endif //_WIN64

...

    
};


//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __fastcall (*FNavigatorEnableChanged)(TBaseNavigator* Self);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE Winapi::Windows::TRect __fastcall DrawButtonFace(Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas* Canvas, const Winapi::Windows::TRect &Client, int BevelWidth, TButtonStyle Style, bool IsRounded, bool IsDown, bool IsFocused);
}   /* namespace Buttons */
}   /* namespace Vcl */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_VCL_BUTTONS)
using namespace Vcl::Buttons;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_VCL)
using namespace Vcl;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // Vcl_ButtonsHPP

File EhLib.VCL.hpp. I can't edit this file. It is autogenerated.
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2024 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'EhLib.VCL.pas' rev: 36.00 (Windows)

#ifndef EhLib_VCLHPP
#define EhLib_VCLHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
#endif
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>
#include <SysInit.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <Data.DB.hpp>
#include <System.TypInfo.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Winapi.Messages.hpp>
#include <System.Generics.Defaults.hpp>
#include <System.Generics.Collections.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.RTLConsts.hpp>
#include <Winapi.Windows.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Winapi.UxTheme.hpp>
#include <System.UITypes.hpp>
#include <EhLibUtils.hpp>
#include <DBUtilsEh.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ImgList.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Graphics.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Themes.hpp>
#include <System.Variants.hpp>
#include <System.Contnrs.hpp>
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Math.hpp>
#include <System.Types.hpp>

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Ehlib
{
namespace Vcl
{
//-- forward type declarations -----------------------------------------------
class DELPHICLASS TWinControlEh;
class DELPHICLASS TCustomControlEh;
struct TDrawTextOptionsEh;
class DELPHICLASS TFilerAccess;
class DELPHICLASS TMemoryStreamEh;
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
typedef Data::Db::TBookmark TUniBookmarkEh;

...

extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::Variant __fastcall RefObjectToVariant(System::TObject* ARefObject);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::TObject* __fastcall VariantToRefObject(const System::Variant &VarValue);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::Types::TPoint __fastcall SafeGetMouseCursorPos(void);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetEhLibGUISysInfoAsString(void);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetEhLibFullSysInfoAsString(void);
}   /* namespace Vcl */
}   /* namespace Ehlib */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB_VCL)
using namespace Ehlib::Vcl;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB)
using namespace Ehlib;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // EhLib_VCLHPP


Please to try to produce a [mre] and include it as text. Images of code and error messages are not acceptable here.

Don't upload images please.  Look for using namespace statements in your code and remove them (specially in header files) and then add the namespaces in front of types that really need them. Also make sure your header files have include guards (e.g. #pragma once).

Also when you develop your own code do NOT reuse the namespace of the library you are using but use a namespace of your own.

I've no experience of Delphi but looking at the generated header files it's clear that you need to define DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE before including the header files. If you do that the problem should go away

@john That hints at "using namespace" in generated header files. (Bad)

@PepijnKramer Yes, the OP quotes an example of exactly that. I guess it was done when they introduced namespaces but also wanted some kind of backwards compatibility.

@DmitryB I already addressed your same question on Delphi-PRAXiS: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/12744-the-c-project-does-not-allow-the-use-of-delphi-units-that-contain-the-text-vcl-in-their-name/ and https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/12739-how-to-properly-configure-delphi-packages-so-that-components-from-these-packages-can-be-used-in-c-builder-projects/ I will copy my answers here as well. FYI, it is generally considered rude etiquette to post the same thing on multiple forums at the same time.

By default, Pascal-generated .hpp headers bring their C++ namespaces into the namespace that is #include'ing the HPP file (which is usually the global scope).  And in this case, since both Vcl namespaces are in the same scope, the compiler doesn't know which one to use, hence the ambiguity error.
If you look closer at the .hpp files, you will notice that those using namespace statements are wrapped in preprocessor blocks, eg:
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_VCL_BUTTONS)
using namespace Vcl::Buttons;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_VCL)
using namespace Vcl;
#endif

#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB_VCL)
using namespace Ehlib::Vcl;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_EHLIB)
using namespace Ehlib;
#endif

So, to avoid the ambiguity, you can specify either DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE or the desired NO_USING_NAMESPACE_... conditional(s) in the "Conditional defines" section of your C++ project's settings.  Or, at least, simply #define them above the relevant #include statement(s) in your C++ code.
Another workaround would be to add {$HPPEMIT NOUSINGNAMESPACE} to your relevant .pas files to avoid any using namespace statements being emitted in their generated .hpp files.
